# Using Tweepy to determine the age on an account

Tags: python, date, twitter, tweepy

I'm looking to use Tweepy for a small project. I'd like to be able to write a bit of code that returns the age of a given Twitter account. The best way I can think of to do this is to return all Tweets from the very first page, find the earliest Tweet and check the date/timestamp on it.

It's a bit hacky but I was wondering if anyone could think of an easier or cleaner way to accomplish this?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Your solution]

```
import tweepy



CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxx'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
user = api.get_user('Obama')
ageTwitterAccount = user.created_at
```

print ageTwitterAccount!

Comment: Why this isn't the marked answer is beyond me.  You provide the same answer while including code that shows exactly what to do and yet people select the answer that just mentions created_at.

Answer (score 1):

The get_user method returns a user object that includes a created_at field.

Check https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users